# How do i keep my code organised when my app needs a helper class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a few custom UIViewControllers in my app which need to know the string returned of an NSDate. I could copy and paste the same code between these classes, but that's obviously terrible practise. It's also probably not good to put it in 1 class as a method, then have another class add this class to take advantage of it's method. It seems like a messy thing to do. So what would you recommend i do?

To clarify - I need a method which is given an NSDate and returns a string, for use in several other classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you either need a *function*, rather than a method:

```
//Helpers.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSString * makeAStringFromThisDateSomehow(NSDate * d);
```

---

```
//Helpers.m

#import "Helpers.h"

NSString * makeAStringFromThisDateSomehow(NSDate * d)
{
    // Body
    // of
    // your
    // function
}
```

Or to make a category on `NSDate` to do what you need:

```
//NSDate+AndrewsCategory.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSDate(AndrewsCategory)
- (NSString *)Andrew_MakeAStringSomehow;
@end
```

---

```
//NSDate+AndrewsCategory.m
#import "NSDate+AndrewsCategory.h"

@implementation NSDate(AndrewsCategory)
- (NSString *)Andrew_MakeAStringSomehow {
    // Body
    // of
    // your
    // method
}

@end
```

Note the stupid prefix on the method name. That's important to keep your method names from colliding with other method names on framework classes. Usually you would use initials: your company's, yours, or the project's.

In either case, just import the relevant header where you need to use the function or method, and you should be hunky-dory.

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider writing a category on `NSDate`. Categories let you extend the functionality of existing classes with additional methods without having to mess with the existing implementation of the class. So you can add `yourMethod` to `NSDate`, and in the future just be able to call `[yourDate yourMethod]`.

To do this in Xcode, just hit ⌘N to create a new file, and choose Objective-C category, then give it some name and make it a category on NSDate.

Then set up your header:

```
@interface NSDate (YourCategory)

- (NSString *) yourMethod;

@end
```

And your implementation:

```
@implementation NSDate (YourCategory)

- (NSString *) yourMethod {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"yourMethod on this date: ", [self description]]; // for example
}

@end
```

Then just include "NSDate+YourCategory.h" in any file where you want to use `yourMethod`.

Answer (score 0):

i'd recommend adding the method to a catagory and then adding the header to your projects pch file

```
#ifdef __OBJC__

#import "yourHeader.h"

#endif
```

if you google for NSDate+Helper that should give you an idea of the implementation.

Nik

Answer (score -1):

It's **probably good** to put it in 1 class as a method, then have another class add this class to take advantage of it's method.
simple 1 or 2 methods NSObject subclasses won't make slightest differences in execution